# Is it possible to multichannel a single channel amp using MultiFX boards?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects

I have a Friedman PT-20, which sounds incredible. As a single channel amplifier meant for mildly overdriven to heavier tones, the only way I can clean up the guitar sound is to roll the volume down. However, lately I have been wanting to add more versatility to my gear, not only by adding some effects (chorus, compressor, delays, etc...) but also by getting different amp sounds through my PT-20.

My question is the following:

With the new multiFXs in the market, like Helix, Headrush, etc., can I create a patch in which I have my guitar going into some boosts (inside the multiFXs board), then going to the front of my PT-20, then have some effects in the loop (like delays and chorus), then the signal going into the power section of my amp and then to the speaker?
Alongside, can I also have a second patch, which the guitar signal goes into the boost + amp-model + effects (w/o cab-sim), then goes to the FX return of my amp (bypassing my PT-20 preamp section) without changing any cable connections?

I know I can use the 4-cable methods with my amp, but my goal is to still have PT-20 sound, coupled with some effects like boost, reverb and delay, but also have the versatility to have extra amps sounds, sort of like having a multichannel amp.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking for gear recommendations is offside here, sorry. A lot of us have gone back to specific individual pedals after the multi board idea. 4-cable is probably the way to go - and if the pedals between pre and post are true by-pass, when off, should give your original sounds. I sometimes use a 'hard-wired' board, with interchangeable pedals, depending on gig, so the plugging in of signal and power is simplified.

Comment: This could be narrowed down to an on-topic question though (perhaps more than one, really, asking for specific ways to use some gear with a particular goal).

Comment: Hi @Julio - I guess if you can edit this to remove the request for which kit etc. That would help make this possible to be reopened

Comment: It seems that Line 6 Helix can do what I originally intended, if any one is interested [link](https://line6.com/support/topic/33948-using-helix-lt-as-means-to-“multichannel”-a-single-channel-amp/?tab=comments#comment-258365).